# publish Azure webrole without public URL

Tags: iis, azure-web-roles, webproxy, azure-vm-role, azure-virtual-network

I setup my own network in Azure, all my data base servers, domain controllers and proxy servers are port of it.

I have web application, hosted to webrole which is part of my azure network by providing following config in service configuration

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
<Dns>
  <DnsServers>
    <DnsServer name="mydc" IPAddress="*.*.*.*" />
  </DnsServers>
</Dns>
<VirtualNetworkSite name="myNet" />
<AddressAssignments>
  <InstanceAddress roleName="mywebrole">
    <Subnets>
      <Subnet name="myfrentendSubnet" />
    </Subnets>
  </InstanceAddress>
</AddressAssignments>
```

I am planning to publish this webrole through my proxy server, I need to create webrole without public URL and should able to access site within my network.

URL should something like http://localhost/mywebrole/index.html

How to configure or publish webrole without public URL ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by setting up your end point as '[InternalEndPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180158.aspx)'.

By setting the end point of your web role to 'internal', it will be accessible only inside of your azure cloud service.

Also, you will have to replace 'localhost' in the URL http://localhost/mywebrole/index.html to 'IP' address of the web role, if you are trying to access from a different web/worker role.

So the ServiceDefinition file would have something like below

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InternalEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />     
</Endpoints>
```